# $.parseJSON giving "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing

I'm parsing a json string with JQuery parseJSON

```
var jsontest = '[{"nombre":"Campa\u00f1a de prueba","parcelas":"10","stampCreacion":"2014-12-30 18:18:26","estado":"1","id":"1","active":"1","camposControl":[{"nombre":"Repetici\u00f3n","tipo":"2","id":"2","active":"1"},{"nombre":"Comentarios","tipo":"1","id":"3","active":"1"}]},{"nombre":"Campa\u00f1a2","parcelas":"10","stampCreacion":"2014-12-30 20:07:36","estado":"1","id":"2","active":"1","camposControl":[{"nombre":"Opciones","tipo":"3","id":"16","active":"1","opciones":[{"nombre":"muchas\r","id":"12","active":"1"},{"nombre":"opciones\r","id":"13","active":"1"},{"nombre":"para mi \r","id":"14","active":"1"},{"nombre":"y para ti","id":"15","active":"1"}]},{"nombre":"numerito por aqui","tipo":"2","id":"17","active":"1"}]}]';



var obj = $.parseJSON(jsontest);
```

It appears to be a valid json according to jsonlint, but as you may see in the fiddle it is giving the next error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -> jquery-1.11.2.min.js:4

http://jsfiddle.net/6a9qLtq2/

I'm using chrome BTW

Answer (score 1):

The errors I see are with your escapes '\'. I replaced all of your \uXXXX codes with \\uXXXX and the only additional errors I got were with your '\r'. I removed the '\r's as well and got this to work:

```
    var jsontest = '[{"nombre":"Campa\\u00f1a de prueba","parcelas":"10","stampCreacion":"2014-12-30 18:18:26","estado":"1","id":"1","active":"1","camposControl":[{"nombre":"Repetici\\u00f3n","tipo":"2","id":"2","active":"1"},{"nombre":"Comentarios","tipo":"1","id":"3","active":"1"}]},{"nombre":"Campa\\u00f1a2","parcelas":"10","stampCreacion":"2014-12-30 20:07:36","estado":"1","id":"2","active":"1","camposControl":[{"nombre":"Opciones","tipo":"3","id":"16","active":"1","opciones":[{"nombre":"muchas","id":"12","active":"1"},{"nombre":"opciones","id":"13","active":"1"},{"nombre":"para mi ","id":"14","active":"1"},{"nombre":"y para ti","id":"15","active":"1"}]},{"nombre":"numerito por aqui","tipo":"2","id":"17","active":"1"}]}]';


var obj = $.parseJSON(jsontest);
console.log(obj);
```

I'm not sure what you were going for with the '\r's, but if you were going for carriage return I think you want '\n'.

As a note about escapes, you have to keep in mind that you have strings within a string, so you have to double escape (the reason why you need two backslashes instead of one).

Oh, and here's a fork http://jsfiddle.net/gok31tqu/

And then for testing, I did another fork where I replaced your '\r' with '\\r' and it appears to run as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/9vktyj29/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -2):

Update JSFiddle to:

```
var jsonstringify = JSON.stringify(jsontest);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonstringify);
```

to encode the backslashes

Comment: Now I'm getting:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '694' in [{"nombre":"Campaña de ...
I changed my php to echo json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); and solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

```
use eval(jsonData) will fix this issue..
```

Comment: can u give me syntax, what u actually use for this?

Comment: Do NOT `eval` a JSON string. Use a function (in the browser or a library) that actually *parses* the JSON. And please don't format everything as "code", only actual code (should be obvious? :) ).